# Making the input boxes width and height 100% with respect to the width and height of the outer div

Tags: html, css

I am not sure what to do here.

I would like to restrict my div's width to 200px and make the input boxes 100% width and height inside the div. As it stands now, it seems that it overflows the width of the div box. Heres a quick pic of the problem (IE10):

[image]

Here's the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<div style="border:1px solid red; height: 20px; width: 200px;">

<input style="background: yellow; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 0;" type="text">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` issue?

Comment: `input { padding:1px }` is set by default in my browser. Adding `padding:0` to `<input>` will fix the problem. As @Paulie_D said, the extra padding causes the width to grow because by the default [`box-sizing`](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html) mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `overflow:hidden;` on the `<div>` see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/B33RG/)**